# Why apps from ppa's are removed during upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, ppa

I understand that ppa's are disabled during upgrade (for a good reason) but I cannot understand why after the upgrade, most apps for which I had ppa's enabled (blender, darktable etc.) are completely missing from my system.

Is it a specific apt situation that sees them as obsolete? Shouldn't they at least be replaced by the official repo versions?

Comment: Keeping, for example, Blender for 14.04 (with all its dependencies) while upgrading to 16.04, would most likely break apt. You are welcome to try and install something build for an older release in 16.04 for reassurance. Just make sure you are ready to reinstall before beginning.